# Add animation into Sprite.draw(SpriteBatch) method

Tags: java, android, ios, animation, libgdx

If it possible to add animation into `Sprite.draw(SpriteBatch)` method. According to proper scaling in multidimensial screens I use viewports and displaying Textures like this:

```
player= new Sprite(new Texture("player.jpg"));
        player.setSize(PLAYER_SIZE,PLAYER_SIZE);
        player.setPosition(0,0);

  @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        player.draw(sb);
        sb.end();
    }
```

I want to animate the movement of my Texture whenever it will move. After searching I found only one way to do this but its required `SpriteBatch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsed_time),position.x,position.y)`, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend looking into Scene2d. this package has all sort of stuff for adding animations to your game: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

Comment: please upvote if the answer below helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to Animation class provided by libgdx
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html

Here goes how it works:

- Create Sprite Map with animation frames using your favorite graphic tool.
- Knowing the dimensions split the Sprite map, i.e.:

  ```
  Texture spritemap = newTexture(Gdx.files.internal("images/sprite-map.png"));
  TextureRegion[][] spritePosition = TextureRegion.split(spritemap, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
  ```
- Next, to create animation class with animation, for example bomb exploding, you will need pick right coordinates from your sprite map, your sprite map is a two dimensional Matrix. So to do it you can for example:

  ```
  TextureRegion[] bombSprites = new TextureRegion[4];
  bombSprites[0] = spritePosition[5][6];
  bombSprites[1] = spritePosition[5][7];
  bombSprites[2] = spritePosition[5][8];
  bombSprites[3] = spritePosition[5][9];
  Animation bombAnimation = new Animation(0.1f, bombSprites);
  ```
- Having Animation prepared, you need to have a class created which extends Actor class. i.e.:

  ```
  public class Bomb extends Actor {

   ... (some fields and methods)
   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    ...
   }
  ```
- You will need to override act method:

  ```
  @Override
  public void act(float delta) {
     this.statetime += delta;
  }
  ```
- after that use batch.draw method in your overridden draw() method to invoke

  ```
  batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(this.statetime, true)
  ```

That's all what's requirement for simple animation

If you need compete example please read the tutorial created by William Mora
http://williammora.com/a-running-game-with-libgdx-part-1

If something is unclear please write it in comment.